# Linear dependency of real numbers with integer coefficients adding up to zero

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, convex-optimization

Let $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ be a vector of real number. I was asking myself if there was an efficient way of telling whether there exists a non-zero vector of integers $z \in \mathbb Z$ such that both
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n z_i = 0$$
and
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n z_i x_i = 0. $$

Is there furthermore some (mild!) condition that one can place on $x$ such that no such vector $z$ exists?

Comment: Without the extra condition on the coefficients, this is just rational independence (which holds generically, of course).

Comment: There are "integer-relation finding algorithms" around, you might want to do a search for those.

Comment: Your question is precisely whether the reals $x_2-x_1$,...,$x_n-x_1$ are linearly independent over the rationals.

Comment: As the question asks whether there is "an *efficient* way of telling whether there exists ...", it seems the OP is interested in the *algorithmic* aspect of figuring out whether some real numbers are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. This has not been addressed by Aaron Meyerowitz' answer, and it depends on how the real numbers are represented.

Answer (score 2):

Given your fixed vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ consider these conditions on a rational vector $q \in \mathbb{Q}^n.$ (scaling will give the integer case.)

$ 1. \sum_{i=1}^n q_i = 0$

and

$ 2. \sum_{i=1}^n q_i x_i = 0. $

The first condition alone determines a subspace $\mathbf{V}$ of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb{Q}^n.$

The second condition alone determines some subspace of $ \mathbf{W} \subset \mathbb{Q}^n.$

The question is when their intersection is other than trivial subspace $\mathbf{0}.$

Two conditions which say the intersection is trivial are

- $\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{0}$ i.e. the $x_i$ are rationally independent. For example:

  - $(1,\pi,\pi^2,\cdots,\pi^{n-1})$ or
  - $(\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_2},\cdots,\sqrt{p_n})$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes or at least pairwise co-prime integers.
- $\mathbf{W}$ is spanned by a single vector not in $\mathbf{V}.$  For example:

  - $(1,r,r^2,\cdots,r^{n-1})$ where $r=\sqrt[n-1]{2}$ or some other root $r \ne 1$ of an irreducible integer polynomial of degree $n-1.$  More generally,
  - $(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})$ rationally independent and $x_n=0$ or indeed any value $x_n=\sum_1^{n-1}c_ix_i$ such that $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sum_1^{n-1}c_i \ne 1.$

However, if $\mathbf{W}$ has dimension at least two then the intersection must be non-trivial.   Specifically, if there are two vectors $q',q''$ , neither a multiple of the other, which satisfy condition 2), then we can find integers $c',c''$ such that $z=c'q'+c''q''$ is an integer vector satisfying both conditions.

Special cases where we can tell that this does happen include

- one of the $x_i=0$ (and the rest are rationally dependent)
- two of $x_i$ are equal and the set of values (without repeats) is dependent.